# Tried to use "pyinstaller <scriptname.py>" and got "TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I want to create a simple yes/no messagebox as one executable file by python. Used pyqt5 and tried make excecutable file with pyinstaller.Got and error

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes).
```

after using command `pyinstaller <scriptname.py>`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox , QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def center(self):
        # geometry of the main window
        qr = self.frameGeometry()

        # center point of screen
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()

        # move rectangle's center point to screen's center point
        qr.moveCenter(cp)

        # top left of rectangle becomes top left of window centering it
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
    def initUI(self):

        self.center()

        buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'PyQt5 message', "Do you like PyQt5?",
                                           QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel, QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('Yes clicked.')
        if buttonReply == QMessageBox.No:
            print('No clicked.')
        if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Cancel:
            print('Cancel')

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: show the complete error message

Answer (score 14):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4265) in someone's comment.

Try to use the latest version compatible with python 3.8.

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
```

This solution worked for me

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow with your answer! When quoting, please use `>` and attribute to the author when possible. A list of all markdown available to help make your posts clearer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Your solution is great! It works to me. But, ummm, there's a typo on your code. you should type "install" instead of "instal"

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller currently doesn't support 3.8. I would suggest you build with 3.7 or earlier until python 3.8 is supported